# How to calculate the Kaprekar numbers in a better way?

Tags: c, algorithm

```
#include <stdio.h>
long power(long y);

int main(void)
{
    long long first, second, number, kaprekar;
    int exponent;
    int helper;
    printf("Let's see all n digits number Kaprekar number\n");
    scanf("%d", &exponent);
    helper = exponent / 2;
    printf("Here are Kaprekar numbers\n");
    for (number = power(exponent - 1); number <= (power(exponent) - 1); number++)
    {
        first = number / (power(helper));
        second = number - (first*(power(helper)));
        if ((first + second)*(first + second) == number)
            printf("%lld\n", number);
    }
    return 0;
}

long power(long y)
{
    long i;
    long j = 10;
    for (i = 1; i< y; i++)
       j *= 10;

    return j;
}
```

First, Kaprekar number is divide the even digits number (like 2010, 102030, 2111, it has even digits, but do have to be even) into two parts, for example, 3025, dividing into two parts, 30 and 25, and (30+25)^2 = 3025. I write a program in order to calculate 14 digits number, but the program runs to slow (in fact, i can get answers until 8 digits number (for example,24502500).

so, can anyone give a better algorithm? Here is my code.

Comment: " divide the even number into two parts" as far as I know 3025 is an odd number :)

Comment: @piyushj sorry to mislead u, I have changed.

Comment: Change `number <= (power(exponent) - 1)` to `number < power(exponent)`, and pre-calculate `power(exponent)` and `power(helper)`.

Comment: Fast and easy optimization: only check numbers that end in 0, 1, 4, 5, 6, or 9 for a 40% efficiency increase.

Comment: Another fast and easy optimization - only check perfect squares. That is numbers x^2 where x ranges from sqrt(10)*10^(helper-1) to 10^helper.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub `power` isn't a problem once it's factored out of the loop

Comment: By the way, 3025 is not a Kaprekar number, 55 is (55^2 = 3025).

Comment: [Wikipedia definition of kaprekar numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaprekar_number) is different than yours.

Comment: @Nelxiost 3025, 30 AND 25, and (35 + 25) = 55, 55^2 = 3025

Comment: @pmg, different? i do think so...

Comment: @Annndy Yeah, and 55 is the Kaprekar one, not 3025. From Wikipedia : "**an integer**, the representation **of whose square** in that base can be split into two parts that add up to **the original number again**". Also the square does not need an even number of digits. In fact, as far as I understand, one can split it into two parts between any two digits.

Comment: @Nelxiost sorry, but in my textbook, it said 3025 is Kaprekar number, let is pretend 3025 is the Kaprekar number, sorry about this concept.

Comment: Have a look at https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Kaprekar_numbers

Comment: 1) `long power(long y)` is inefficient.  2) " i can get answers until 8 digits number" --> change function code and signature: `long long power(long y)`

Comment: the posted code has a usability problem.  When the posted code is run, it outputs a 'title' line and leaves the user looking at a blinking cursor, with no indication of what to do next.  Suggest to always prompt the user when ever some data is to be entered.

Comment: a run of the program outputs: `Let's see all n digits number Kaprekar number
5
Here are Kaprekar numbers
10000`   However, where is the 'kaprekar' numbers?

Comment: @user3629249 please try 4 or 6 or 8 even numbers, my problems is that this program can find the Kaptekar numbers when n = 10 or 12 and so on.

Comment: @chux I changed long long power(long y), still can not get…

Comment: @WeatherVane I changed, it gets faster when n =  4, 6, and 8. but still can not get Kaprekar numbers when n = 10... actually, i get answers after 2 mins on my Macbook Air...    I do think maybe my whole algorithm is not good, so can you give some suggestions?

Comment: Did you try the suggestion from @DmitriChubarov?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every Kaprekar number with 2n digits is the square of a number with n digits, so to find all of the Kaprekar numbers below 10^14, inspect the squares of all numbers below 10^7.  However, the square of some n digit numbers is only 2n - 1: these will not work.  To avoid these, for every power of 10 <= 10^7, start at that power divided by the square root of 10 and go up to that power of ten.  I wrote a program that does this, and it runs in 0.6 seconds.  The reason it is so much faster is because it is checking only about 10^6.5 numbers whereas your program checks 10^14.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

const uint64_t DIGITS = 14;

int main(void){
    uint64_t top = 10;
    for(uint64_t i = DIGITS/1; i-- > 0;){//calculate 10^(DIGITS/2) using iterated multiplication (better exponentiation is unnecessary.)
        top *= 10;
    }
    for(uint64_t t = 10; t <= top; t *= 10){
        for(uint64_t n = t*.316227766016838L; n < t; ++n){//divide t by the square root of 10 to ensure n*n has twice as many digits as n.
            uint64_t k = n*n;
            if(n == k%t + k/t){
                printf("%"PRIu64"\n", k);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: there is a catch: n=10^7 is not a Kaprekar number, because n*n%10^7 is 0. You have to check that k%t is nonzero.

Comment: @ead Yes, but this code never looks at perfect powers of 10 because for every power of 10 t it looks at all n on [t/sqrt(10), t).  This means n can never be a perfect power of 10, and since it is an integer neither can k = n*n.